# Proptypes function react native Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

Hi everybody im making a new app at react native using tsx and i have a question.

Im have three props at screen, one boolean and two functions, my question is
there is a way of to define a proptype function without to use "any" type?  using js with "proptypes" i can to use proptypes "function" but i do not have idea of how to make this using typescript

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Modal, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';

interface propTypes {
  isVisible : boolean,
  scanCallback: any,
  OnCloseModal: any
}


const ScannerModal = ({isVisible, scanCallback, OnCloseModal}: propTypes) => {

  if (!isVisible) {
    return null
  }
  
  const onBarCodeRead = (e : {data : string, type: string}) => {
    scanCallback(e.data, e.type)
  }
  return (
      .....
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like

```
interface propTypes {
  isVisible : boolean,
  scanCallback: (_data: string, _type: string) => void,
  OnCloseModal: () => void
}
```

Here is a [helpful guide](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#basic-prop-types-examples) on using typescript in react. It also applies to react-native.